# can i implement two app widgets for an application?

Tags: android

I am developing a Player application for a radio, I need to implement two app widget players for two radio stations individually.

Can i implement two app widgets for an application.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, the Twitter application has two widgets, depending on size.  You aren't limited to only one, though it may be harder to dynamically create a new widget every time the user adds a new radio station.  In that type of scenario, it would be better to have a single widget that could be configured to point to a different station, since the code would really be the same and you can have multiple widget instances running at once.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely can. Just define two app-widget providers.